# Проблема в ноде Python Script в Dynamo, Revit 2023

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго времени суток! Проблема с нодом со скриптом на Python (Dynamo 2.13.1.3887, Revit 2.13.1.3891):

```
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

view = UnwrapElement(IN[0])

iels = [ElementId(int(eid)) for eid in IN[1]]
for eid in IN[1]:
    iels.append(eid)
    
if iels:
    view.HideElements(iels)

TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
```

Ошибка следующая:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'HideElements' [' File "', line 17, in >module<\n'].
В Python я не знаю почти ничего, уже второй день не могу решить ошибку. Максимум пытался потыкаться в интернете на предмет ошибок и пообщаться со всем известной нейросетью.

Изначально скрипт должен скрывать все элементы в IN[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMpIv.jpg) (список L1 SectionView) на видах IN[0] (список L2 StructuralPlanView). На вход подаются, собственно, эти значения списком.

Прикладываю весь скрипт в Dynamo. Буду благодарен, если сможете помочь инвертировать скрипт, т.е. скрывать все виды (разрезы), кроме тех, что в списке IN[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMpIv.jpg). Пишется скрипт для автоматизации создания сотен листов, поэтому ручной выбор не рассматривался изначально.
[image: Полный скрипт в Dynamo]

По необходимости могу прислать сам скрипт на Dynamo.

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Дополнение:
При попытке получить код элемента вылезает ошибка No constructor matches given arguments: (class 'Revit.Elements.Views.SectionView') ... line 10 ...

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

iels = ElementId(IN[0])
    
OUT = iels
```

На вход подается одно значение SectionView

Дополнение №2:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

view = UnwrapElement(IN[0])

iels = IN[1].get_Id()

iels_visibility = iels.__getattribute__(BuiltInParameter.GRAPHICS_VISIBLE)
iels_visibility.Set(0)
    
OUT = iels
```

Данный код все еще не работает, но одна из главных проблем найдена - в Revit 2023 поменялись некоторые операторы (например, ElementId(test) заменен на test.get_Id(), и так во многом).
Решил сначала проверить код не на списках, а на отдельных элементах... Ошибка следующая:

[image: Ошибка после кода в дополнении №2]

Comment: Ну видимо во `view` у вас простой питоновский список получается. Что вы хотите сделать с этим списком?

Comment: @CrazyElf если про то, что поступает через UnwrapElement в IN-0 - то это список видов на которых нужно скрыть список видов, поступающих в список IN-1. Подсказали, что проблема в том, что на вход функции подается 'list', у которого нет нужного атрибута. И поэтому надо из списка вытаскивать один элемент, присваивать ему определенный тип, скрывать его и после менять значение на следующее из списка, но как это сделать я не знаю, так как изучал только Pascal и то на весьма примитивном уровне. И буду премного благодарен за решение проблемы

Comment: У вас столько ошибок в коде, что с каждой надо разбираться отдельно и её починка не приведёт к рабочему коду, а приведёт только к следующей ошибке. Лучше вы попробуйте сами поразбираться прямо вот с каждой строкой отдельно. Вы можете, я в вас верю. Смотрите руководства - какие параметры у функций и т.д. А так это мы долго будем копаться. Поразбирайтесь, как совсем опять затык будет - возвращайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Если я всё правильно понял из вашего комментария, то перебрать элементы списка и сделать с ними нужное возможно так:

```
for item in view:
    item.HideElements(iels)
```

Comment: Исправил код следующим образом:
`import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

view = UnwrapElement(IN[0])

iels = [ElementId(eid) for eid in IN[1]]
for item in view:
    item.HideElements(iels)
    

TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
`
Вылезла ошибка no constructor matches given arguments: (class 'list') (прошу прощения за вид кода, у меня не хочет он становится нормальным)

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, там нормально можно отформатировать. И полный стек-трейс новой ошибки тоже туда.